# Graphing and linear algebra libraries to Ruby for machine learning visualization?

Tags: ruby, graph, rubygems, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I aim to code some machine learning algorithms in Ruby and searching for good candidate libraries for visualization and linear algebra to make me feel like in Matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- linear algbra: [linalg](http://linalg.rubyforge.org/)
- for data visualization, check http://effectif.com/ruby/manor/data-visualisation-with-ruby